# What is the correct mapping for the Homestead.yaml? I am returning “No input file specified”

Tags: laravel, terminal, vagrant, homestead

I am returning “No input file specified” from the following code, I am sure the mapping is correct could there be another cause?

```
    provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/web/
      to: /home/vagrant/web

sites:
    - map: PGM.app
      to: /home/vagrant/web/PGM/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your path is correct and that ~/web/PGM/public exists.

If everything is in order then it's probably a permissions error.  Make sure that ~/web/PGM/storage and ~/web/PGM/bootstrap/cache are fully accessible:

```
chmod 0777 ~/web/PGM/storage -R
chmod 0777 ~/web/PGM/bootstrap/cache -R
```

Then make sure that PGM.app is in your /etc/hosts.  It should be like this:

```
192.168.10.10 PGM.app
```

Last, if you made a modification to your Homestead.yaml file, make sure to run provision.

```
cd /path/to/Homestead/
vagrant provision
```

You can also try to rebuild de VM

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

You can read more about this problem here:

http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-no-input-file-specified-using-homestead